# Why NaN is returned by a post-increment operator?

Tags: javascript, nan, post-increment

When the following line of code is executed in node.js console the result is:

```
var string = 'abc'; string++;
// NaN
string;
// NaN
```

I thought that it should work like this:

```
var string = 'abc'; string++;
// 'abc';
string;
// NaN
```

My rationale:

> Because `++` is a post-increment operator, meaning it returns the old value (in this case `abc`) and then it adds `1` to the **string**, gets `abc1`, which is *Not A Number*, but the `++` operator should return a nubmer, so it returns special`NaN` number and assigns it to variable **string**

Please specify where I am wrong.

Comment: What is `s`? When I run your code in Node I immediately get a reference error.

Comment: What is `s`? Should that be `string++`?

Comment: @isherwood Yes it should. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that the `++` "postfix" increment operator works involves first performing a conversion to number type. The value of that conversion is always the return value from the operation, even if that value is `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

`++` if used on a string , first tries to convert it to a number if the conversion fails you get `NaN`.